# Form validation is not working in XAmp

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

Iam using Xaamp server for my codeigniter project and the project path is xaamp/htdocs/my_proj .And iam using `form_validation` library for my registration page and in my controller I have loaded it like

```
$this->load->library('Form_validation');
```

and in my function I have put validation like

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|min_length[5]|max_length[25]');
```

but If I write like this and if I submit form it showing me blank screen may be it indicated that library is not loaded.So what can I do to get rid from this situtation.If i comment this line and print the `POST` username it is printing.Thanks in advance..

Comment: A blank screen typically indicates an error, but you have error displaying turned off. Google it.

Answer (score 1):

If its not a typo you are using `Form_validation` library to load, but it should be `form_validation`. See the difference.

```
$this->load->library('Form_validation');
                      ^ // here F is in capital letters.
```

should be

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
                      ^ // here f is in small letters.
```